# Brief info hotkey in intelliJ on mac

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm able to see Brief info on my IntelliJ on Ubuntu via Ctrl + mouse over on code as you see in https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf.

However, it doesn't work on my mac. I tried Ctrl + mouse over and Command + mouse over but neither of them is working.

How can I do this on Mac, if I hold Ctrl + mouse over on code, then I'd like to see the brief info on MAC.

[image]

Comment: have the same problem(